If I publish a WinUI 3 app with the SingleFile setting then can I sign the containing dlls somehow?
I am experimenting with WinUI 3 and my question is that I saw the option SingleFile which creates a single .exe at publishing.
My company requires us that each dll that we publish with our apps has to be signed. So if I would choose single file publishing then how would it work?

Can Strong-name signing  meet your needs?
